Connecting to AWS RDS MYSQL DB from Centos based VPS
I have a VPS (virtual private server) hosted on Hostinger, the web server on the VPS is managed by CyberPanel.
On AWS, I have a MySql DB that I can access it from my PC using WorkBench and from my VPS using its Terminal.
The problem occurs when i try to connect to the DB from php web page.
I get the following error:
Connection failed: Unknown database 'my-database'
Here is the php code:
$host = "*************.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
$username = "user";
$password = "*************";
$dbname = "my-database";
$port = 3306;

// Create a new connection to the MySQL database
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

I am sure that the connection details are correct.
I tried to run "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1" on my VPS and I got "setsebool:  SELinux is disabled."
Any idea how to connect to AWS RDS DB from the php web page?

Please remove the "check connection" part. See Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?

The error indicates that the code could successfully connect to mysql, but the database orovided in the parameter does not exists. If the database name truly has a dash in it, then try using backticks around the database name.

I removed the if connection check and created a new db called dbdev, and I still getting the error: Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'dbdev' in test.php on line 275
Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in test.php on line 286
